# Assigning $\pm 1$ values to the edges of a complete graph

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, combinations, algebraic-graph-theory

I read this sentence in one combinatorics book.

> In graph $K_{100}$, there is a possible way to assigns number (value) from $\{+1,-1\}$ to each edge, so that the sum of all edge values connected to each vertex becomes $+1$.

I try to understand it, but I could not verify it. Please help me.

Comment: Try cleaning up the wording and adding more information here, since the question is currently not very comprehensible.

Answer (score 5):

Proof by induction:

For every complete graph $K_{2n}$ with $2n$ vertices, there is a labeling of the edges with ${-1,+1}$ such that every vertex has $n$ edges labeled $+1$ and $n-1$ edges labeled $-1$.

The claim is trivially true for the null graph since there are no vertices.  For the graph $K_2$, label the single edge $+1$.

Take a graph $K_{2n}$ labeled as described above.  Divide its set of vertices into two subsets of equal size: $V = V_1 \cup V_2$, $|V_1|=|V_2|=n$.  Add two new vertices $x$ and $y$.  Add edges and labels as follows:

- Edges connecting $x$ to all vertices in $V_1$ are labeled $+1$.
- Edges connecting $y$ to all vertices in $V_1$ are labeled $-1$.
- Edges connecting $x$ to all vertices in $V_2$ are labeled $-1$.
- Edges connecting $y$ to all vertices in $V_2$ are labeled $+1$.
- The edge $xy$ is labeled $+1$.

Vertices in $V_1$ each gained one edge labeled $+1$ to $x$ and one labeled $-1$ to $y$, so they now have $n+1$ edges labeled $+1$ and $n$ edges labeled $-1$.  Similarly, vertices in $V_2$ each gained two edges of opposite sign, so they also have $n+1$ labeled $+1$ and $n$ labeled $-1$.  $x$ has $n$ edges labeled $+1$ to $V_1$, $n$ edges labeled $-1$ to $V_2$, and one edge labeled $+1$ to $y$, for a total of $n+1$ labeled $+1$ and $n$ labeled $-1$.  The same way, $y$ also has $n+1$ edges labeled $+1$ and $n$ labeled $-1$.

So we have constructed a labeling of $K_{2n+2}$ that satisfies the induction hypothesis.  Such a labeling is possible for all complete graphs with even vertex count.

Comment: The induction is unnecessary: for $K_{2n}$ divide the vertices into sets $V_1, V_2$ both of size $n$. Assign $+1$ to any edge connecting the two halves, assign $-1$ to edges that stay in the same half.

Comment: Dear @aschelper for $K_{99,100}$ it's not possible. Am i right? Thanks

Comment: What's not possible? Note that in $K_{99,100}$ some vertices have $99$ edges and others have $100$.

Comment: I means the above question for $K_{100}$ is true but for $K_{99,100}$ is false. Am i correct? Thx